# Why am I getting an error when I try to get a response by id?

Tags: flutter

I want to consume the jikanapi api, reviewing the documentation says that with this url I can get an anime by id. and when copying the url in the browser I get the following.

```
{
  "status": 404,
  "type": "HttpException",
  "message": "Not Found",
  "error": null
}
```

It must be because I didn't pass an ID but I don't really know how to do it. although in the demo you don't pass any id and you get a response.

[image]

Comment: You might've  forgotten to pass ID

Comment: In the example, it didn't pass any ID because the return info was a sample response.   You need to pass an ID to the api.

Comment: api.jikan.moe/v4/anime/{0}/videos would it be this way? I do not know exactly,try to replace the "id" with a number

Comment: [https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime/20/full](https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime/20/full)  See here what a [query params](https://www.botify.com/learn/basics/what-are-url-parameters) does.

Comment: The thing is: do you know what id to use? it actually exits in the api?
Try call api.jikan.moe/v4/anime/3, it does return, but with id 0 ou 4 it says there is not object.
This doesn't seem as a flutter problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are doing a wrong GET request.

I tried the following URLs and all worked:

https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime         --> gives full list

[https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime/{id}/full](https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime/%7Bid%7D/full)  --> gives full description. change "{id}" to your id example: /v4/anime/1/full

in flutter you can concatinate the url into a single string if you want to apply filters before sending the GET request.

Example:

```
int myId = 1;
String myURL = "https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime/${myId}/full";
```